# OAuth Developer Verification form questions

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I've completed the OAuth Developer Verification form today. However, I received no response or an e-mail with a tracking number. For the moment, there is no place to track the application. Anyone knows if they planned to develop a tracking ? Is there any email, telephone to contact the Developers team ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no tracker. But we are resolving these requests in 2 to 5 business days. If you don't hear back, let me know.